# Hudson CI "Excluded Regions" can't filter folder?

Tags: hudson

I'm using Hudson CI for my project. However i faced a problem. Hope someone can guide me...

I want to check out some code from SVN by using Hudson CI. However i want to select certain folders to be check out only. I tried " Excluded Regions" provided in Hudson advanced settings...

Like said i want to filter folder "folderA". i don't want this folder check out from svn when i hit build link at Hudson. 
Therefore i write "folderA" at the excluded regions text field. But it doesn't work.

Anyone knows why it does not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Excluded regions determines what constitutes a change, i.e. a change in an excluded region will not trigger a build. the entire source tree is always checked out (starting from the root you specified).

Comment: hi, thanks for your quick response. May i know is there any ways to check out certain folders from the given SVN URL in Hudson CI?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to check out the code yourself rather than letting Hudson do it for you.

Comment: You can always check out a single folder (or hierarchy) with Subversion, so you could add multiple SVN sources to Hudson if you want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; Look at a change under a recent build and see what relative path Jenkins is using for your repository.

I wanted to ignore all changes to files and folders under http://server/svn/MyProjectName/trunk/src/folder/

I looked under Changes in one of the most recent builds and it showed a change was made to /MyProjectName/trunk/src/folder/filename.txt

So to exclude all files and folders under /MyProjectName/trunk/src/folder/ I put /MyProjectName/trunk/src/folder/.*

Hope this helps anyone else that has had trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of telling what Hudson should not check out, you can also configure what Hudson should check out (add another subversion location). Of course this only works if you want to eliminate one of the top level folders.

e.g.

- Project

  - subproject 1

    - subproject 1.1
    - subproject 1.2
  - subproject 2
  - subproject 3
  - subproject 4

So you can elemintate the whole subproject 1 but not subproject 1.1 if there are files in subproject1.

This gets pretty messy though when you have many subprojects. I am not sure for what SCMs it will work, however, it can be done with subversion.

Usually I would try to avoid checking code out from subversion myself, since you will loose the change detection provided by Hudson. Without change detection, you have only the periodic build as an option, meaning it builds regardless if there are changes in your project or not.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. It's very helpful. May i know, instead of checking out the folders from the SVN respository, how & what should i do at Hudson CI if i just want to check out only a certain file?

Comment: try the whole path to the file in subversion (including file name). Haven't tried that but I would expect that to work just fine.

Comment: Subversion doesn't like to check out individual files. You'll get an error like "... refers to a file, not a directory." If you need just a file, you have to mess with --depth, see http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html#sparse-checkouts

Comment: Yes i get error that's why i ask question here ytd ... :| erm.... never mind, maybe i try not to check out only certain files. can --depth works in CI hudson? Or just svn command? 
another question: how do i install Hudson in the Tomcat at UNIX ? Where should i set my HUDSON_HOME and JVM those stuff?

Comment: Sorry i asked stupid Question just now.... i know the solution. Just put the hudson.war into the tomcat_home/webapps/ folder